# No access to service static fields from activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-service

I am trying to set the boolean value in the service static field to indicate whether service is running or not. The problem is that that value in the activity I am calling the service from and where I perform the checking is always returning false! even at the moment when I check for that value inside service class it is true. Is it because of some kind of thread lock or why?

**UPD:**
My service and main activity are run in the different processes ( declared in android Manifest ). I searched more for this question and right now I think I will stick with using Application context

**UPD2:**
Switched to single process and extended Application class to use common context

Comment: Are the Service and Activity in different processes? Also, post some relevant code.

Comment: If your service and activities are running in different processes,then you won't be able to share information in the Application context either. There will be an instance of the Application object in **each** process.